# Border-Radius, overflow and Full screen

Tags: css, hidden

I have looked at a lot of questions since reducing my problem to the bare-minimum, but I havn't seen a proper solution yet.

For a project I have to place a TinyMCE within a "window" that has border-radius. Now when using the full-screen plugin of TinyMCE the editor breaks at the corners of the "window" and there is just some parts missing (they are there and can be clicked, but the rendering just does not happen)

I have a CodePen with minimal Code here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoWWJo 
The expected result should be that the green box covers the whole screen, but at the corners of the "underlaying" x-layer it gets either cut-out (Chrome) or it just stays within the "window" (FireFox).

```css
.x-layer {
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF0000;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 19011;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #00FF00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="x-layer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

I know this has been working in the past without a problem, so either something in the handling of the combination has changed or something else is broken, which I cannot see right now.

Problem I have is that I only have limited possibilities to change both CSS and the HTML layout of the components.

[image: Screenshot of the actual project]

Comment: Maybe try some padding?

Comment: if i understand well, when you click somewhere to make the green div at full screen, it keeps with border-radius and you don't want it to work as if, right?

Comment: A guess (not good enough of one to make an answer out of) is that an empty div element of one of the ribbon's drop downs is what you're seeing as the "cut-out" element. Can you check for any CSS name collisions? Maybe `inner` is defined elsewhere...

Comment: Your .inner is using fixed positioning, so it's *always* positioned relative to the viewport.  If you want it to be positioned relative to your x-layer, you need to use absolute or relative positioning.

Comment: Use padding my guy!

Comment: Well the "inner" div is representing the fullscreen view of the TinyMCE (so it is fixed positioned, because it is supposed to take up the full screen)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed position is always positioned relative to the viewport.  I assume you're trying to maximize the amount of space for the editor, but your overflow: hidden will prevent buttons on the corners from being 'accessible', so the best solution is to simply move the inner element down by 5px.

To create an inner element that is positioned within your absolute positioned x-layer, you can use absolute positioning such as:

```css
.x-layer {
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF0000;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 19011;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;  
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #00FF00;
  z-index: 100;  
}
```

```html
<div class="x-layer">    
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or relative positioning, such as:

```css
.x-layer {
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF0000;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 19011;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;  
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00FF00;
  z-index: 100;  
}
```

```html
<div class="x-layer">    
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not trying to put the inner div inside the x-layer. But i think I will try to change the "overflow: hidden" to "overflow: visible" when clicking on the full screen option. That seems the most practical at the moment